# How to control media player with SeekBar

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am trying to control media player with seekbar, but whenever i do tap on seekbar its reached at the end of seekbar, see my code below:

```
          seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

              @Override
              public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

              }

              @Override
              public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

              }

                  @Override
                  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                      if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                          mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                      }
                  }
          });
```

what i am missing ? where i am doing mistake ? where i have to make changes in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Progress bar returns correct position already. You don't need to multiply it by 1000. This should solve the issue.

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
    if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me, i will accept your answer within next 6minutes